# Using GDAL to convert PBF to MVT for use in Mapbox

Tags: gdal, pbf

Is it possible to convert PBF file formats to MVT so that I can correctly view them on Mapbox using GDAL?

originally looked at `ogr2ogr` but that returned this message which I don't quite understand `Warning 1: Input datasource uses random layer reading, but output datasource does not support random layer writing`

Comment: If PBF means OpenStreetMap data files https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html it might be easier to convert OSM data into PostGIS or GeoPackege first and write MVT https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html from there. But converting OSM data first into GIS layers and then into MVT layers is rather complicated, though doable. I would search the web and select a tutorial that feels best to follow.